# Facebook graph object/entity parsing SDK 4 in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, option-type

In Swift how do you parse the result of a fbk graph request? I have a nested dictionary and casting to [String: String] does not work. I have casted to NSDictionary which works for level 1 but anything nested started complaining about optionals and casting. I see from the changeling that FBGraphObject has been deprecated, so what is the correct approach now in SDK 4?

My data looks like

```
{
    data = {
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "...";
    };
}
```

I can do

```
var data = photoRes["data"] as? NSDictionary
```

to get

```
Optional({
    "is_silhouette" = 0;
    url = "...;
})
```

I'm not sure how to parse that object...

**EDIT** For now I have it working with

```
var data = photoRes["data"] as? NSDictionary
var urlStr = data!["url"] as? String
if urlStr != nil {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)
    //my code...
}
```

But this is a complicated approach especially if the result coming back is highly nested. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: do you want to get the url of picture ?

Comment: no that does not work - it cannot parse the result of 'photoRes["data"]'

Comment: i don't know what you mean and regardless you're missing the point of the question. it's a general question about how to parse the response object from a graph request. is there a class provided I can cast this to or do I need to use some third party son lib?

Comment: you have to check the edited answer. may you get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dict : NSDictionary!
}
```

Fetching the data :

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            self.dict = result as NSDictionary               
            println(self.dict)
            NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
        }
    })
}
```

Output should be :

```
{
    email = "ashishkakkad8@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Ashish;
    id = 910855688971343;
    "last_name" = Kakkad;
    name = "Ashish Kakkad";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/22501_915701971820048_9046303472199214595_n.jpg?oh=f3b3564f1450c13332b3067a135cad5d&oe=55C71792&__gda__=1443571904_c4667dcb08d85682edfd77a90ee9c3ab";
        };
    };
}
2015-05-25 22:12:34.015 SwiftFB[2713:7830] https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/22501_915701971820048_9046303472199214595_n.jpg?oh=f3b3564f1450c13332b3067a135cad5d&oe=55C71792&__gda__=1443571904_c4667dcb08d85682edfd77a90ee9c3ab
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this for hours!

Comment: did not helped me

Comment: @RayKing Yes. Because this is old code. Go Here http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/

Answer (score 0):

This mess worked for me. I am using SWIFT 3.01 and FB Swift SDK

```
if let responseDictionary = response.dictionaryValue {

                    print(responseDictionary["name"] ?? "")

                    let a = responseDictionary["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                    let b = a["data"] as! NSDictionary
                    let c = b["url"]
                    print(c ?? "")
```