# iOS Swift Facebook SDK 4 getting user profile picture outputs "Question Mark"

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am not an expert in programming, but I modified a code to get the user profile picture from Facebook SDK. The problem is I am getting a Question Mark in the image (`profilePicture.image`). Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Also, I am not sure what how to call this function to get image in viewController? At present I am directly adding profilePicture.image inside the function.

```
   func getProfPic(fid: String) -> UIImage? {
            if (fid != "") {
                var imgURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fid + "/picture?type=large" //type=normal
                var imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString)
                var imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
                var image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                profilePicture.image = image // Returned image is Question mark 
                return image
            }
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: You can refer this answer for facebook picture large : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30439458/3202193 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346876/ios-facebook-sdk-4-session/30352673#30352673

Comment: Thanks @AshishKakkad. But I still don't know how to display image? I have never seen is_silhouette while dealing with images. Can you please tell me how to get the image in my image output "profilePicture.image = ?"

Comment: I don't know how to get the large picture as you are doing. Sorry. @Vicky

Comment: @AshishKakkad Sorry I didn't clarify. But I am using your reference code only. It is giving me results as expected. My question is, in the results I see picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10801813_342292552609289_1231153625491611755_n.jpg?oh=b75d1a2f2934a047900fab82e17c718b&oe=5644FA5C&__gda__=1448033237_fabc6a223c12131199db908c6fe476f9";
        };
I can see that there is an image, but how  to get it in the UIImage outlet (profilePicture) on uiviewcontroller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dictionary :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dict : NSDictionary!
}
```

Fetching the data :

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            self.dict = result as NSDictionary               
            println(self.dict)
            NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
        }
    })
}
```

Output should be :

```
{
    email = "ashishkakkad8@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Ashish;
    id = 910855688971343;
    "last_name" = Kakkad;
    name = "Ashish Kakkad";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/22501_915701971820048_9046303472199214595_n.jpg?oh=f3b3564f1450c13332b3067a135cad5d&oe=55C71792&__gda__=1443571904_c4667dcb08d85682edfd77a90ee9c3ab";
        };
    };
}
2015-05-25 22:12:34.015 SwiftFB[2713:7830] https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/22501_915701971820048_9046303472199214595_n.jpg?oh=f3b3564f1450c13332b3067a135cad5d&oe=55C71792&__gda__=1443571904_c4667dcb08d85682edfd77a90ee9c3ab
```

Convert Image from URL

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/22501_915701971820048_9046303472199214595_n.jpg?oh=f3b3564f1450c13332b3067a135cad5d&oe=55C71792&__gda__=1443571904_c4667dcb08d85682edfd77a90ee9c3ab") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
        yourImageview.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```